# Triplet form of Sparse matrix, getting wrong output in first Row

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, sparse-matrix, dynamic-memory-allocation

*Hello Friends, I was trying to make **Triplet form of a sparse matrix using pointers and DMA** but **the output in first row is returning garbage values** can anyone help me in resolving this issue.*

---

```
int main(){
    int k=0,z=0,arr[6][6]={
                       {15,0,0,22,0,-15},
                       {0,11,3,0,0,0},
                       {0,0,0,-6,0,0},
                       {0,0,0,0,0,0},
                       {91,0,0,0,0,0},
                       {0,0,28,0,0,0}
                       };
    int **trip=new int *[3];
    for(int i=0;i<6;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<6;j++){
            if (arr[i][j]==0){
                z++;
            }
            else{
                trip[k]=new int(1);
                trip[k][0]=i;                
                trip[k][1]=j;
                trip[k][2]=arr[i][j];
                k++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
Output-
-65511600 22028 -65511568 
0 3 22 
0 5 -15 
1 1 11 
1 2 3 
2 3 -6 
4 0 91 
5 2 28

Expected Output
0 0 15
0 3 22 
0 5 -15 
1 1 11 
1 2 3 
2 3 -6 
4 0 91 
5 2 28
```

Comment: If this is not intended as a purely academic exercise (e.g.: homework assignment) I would strongly suggest you use the [Eigen template library](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) for this.

Comment: `trip[k]=new int(1);` allocates a single `int`. The only valid index is `trip[k][0]`. Yet the program goes right ahead and accesses `trip[k][1]`, thereby exhibiting undefined behavior.

Comment: You claim that the code shown generates incorrect output - but there are no statements in it that can possibly produce any output at all. The output you show must have come from some other program. Show a [mcve].